# Does this integral condition characterize $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary. For any $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$, is it true that $f \in L^\infty (\Omega)$ if and only if the following condition holds?

For every $\delta > 0$, there exists some $C > 0$ such that for almost every $x \in \Omega$, and every open ball $B \subset \Omega$ centered at $x$ with radius at least $\delta$ we have

$$|f(x)| \leq C \def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_B |f|.$$

*Note: Here $\def \avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_B |f|$ denotes the average integral of $|f|$ over $B$.*

*Edit:* The original question asked about the case where the balls $B$ are not necessarily centered at $x$. This has been solved in the comments - the "if" direction holds, but "only if" does not.

Comment: Concerning the "only if" part: the value of $f(x)$ is not even defined at any $x$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Oh, let’s say that $f$ is not an equivalence class of functions, but an actual (measurable) representative of an element of $L^\infty$. Also, I have to specify almost everywhere.

Comment: I think convex unbounded functions provide counterexamples when $d = 1$.

Comment: @Zarrax Actually I don't think this is true. For convex functions you might not have the inequality in the OP, check for example $f(x)=1/x^2, B=(\varepsilon,1), x = \varepsilon.$

Comment: Do you want the radius to be bigger or smaller than $\delta$?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune bigger!

Comment: But then fix $\delta=1$ and get $|f(x)| \leq C \int_B |f| \leq C\|f\|_1$..or I misunderstood?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I believe I do have a proof of the “if” implication, which I will type up soon. The “only if” is the troubling direction.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Concerning your earlier comment, $B$ has to be contained within $\Omega$.

Comment: For large radius RHS goes to 0 for any function $f\in L^1$, does not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes indeed, however balls of large radius contained in $\Omega$ need not exist.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed this. But then does not only if part simply say that for small enough $\delta$ the union of balls of radius $\delta$ contained in $\Omega$ is the whole $\Omega$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov as in, that condition implies the only if part? I believe it implies the if part but I don’t see the converse.

Comment: @FedorPetrov By the way, that condition is indeed true by the uniform interior sphere lemma, which holds as soon as $\Omega$ has $C^2$ boundary.

Comment: Ugh.. only if doesn’t hold - any step function is a counterexample.

Comment: Amusingly if one demands the balls to be centered, then I think the "only if" holds but the "if" fails.

Comment: Ah, yes, if part.

Comment: Well, what if $\Omega=(-2,2)$, $f$ is 0 on $(-1,1)$ and 1 otherwise, $\delta=1$? There seem to be no $C$...

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes indeed, the “only if” direction fails horribly. Although, see my comment directly before this one.

Comment: Yes, for centered balls there is $C$ such that this works for all Lebesgue points of $f$

Comment: Now I missed most of your discussion. What is true and what fails? Maybe also an answer could be useful.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune As stated in the current post, “if” holds while “only if” fails. If on the other hand, the balls $B$ are required to be centered at $x$, then “only if” holds but “if” fails. Very strange how such a small difference completely reverses the implications…

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Should be said that the one claim I am not 100% sure of is that “if” fails in the centered formulation. It could be the case that I am mistaken about my heuristic counterexample.

Comment: Why the only if part holds for centered balls?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I think I spoke too soon indeed. I thought to use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, but the points at which the convergence in the theorem is slow pose an issue. Now I have no idea about either implication for the centered case...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me prove that for $f\in L^\infty$ and fixed $\delta>0$ (and centered balls) such $C$ exists. The idea is to find $C$ which works for *all* Lebesgue points of $f$. Assume that there is no such $C$, then for $C=n$ there exist violating Lebesgue points $x_n$ and $B_n$ with center $x_n$ and radius $r_n\geqslant \delta$ and $$|f(x_n)|> n\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{B_n}|f|.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$
Without loss of generality, $x_n$ converge to a point $x_0$ (it lies in $\Omega$, since all $x_n$ are at distance at least $\delta$ from $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Omega$, thus so does $x_0$). Then for the ball $B(x_0,\delta)$ we have $\int_{B(x_0,\delta)}f=0$: otherwise the integrals over $B_n$ would be bounded from below, and RHS's of $(\heartsuit)$ would tend to infinity, contradicting to LHS's being bounded from above by $\|f\|_\infty$. But for large $n$ we have $x_n\in B(x_0,\delta)$, and, since by $(\heartsuit)$ we have $f(x_n)\ne 0$ and $x_n$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, we conclude that $f$ is non-zero on some set of positive measure inside $B(x_0,\delta)$. A contradiction.

For other direction, for centered balls this trivially fails for example for $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$, $\Omega=(0,1)$ (for $x$ near the singularity there are simply no centered balls of radius $\geqslant \delta$ contained in $\Omega$). For not centered balls it is However true, and settled in comments, the key word is uniform interior sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment. For $d=1$ should be true. Let me simplify a bit (hopefully without loss of generality). If $\Omega=(-1,1), f\in C(-1,1)$. Then what you ask implies that
\begin{equation} f(x) \leq A + B \int_0^x f(t) dt \leq A + B \int_0^x f(t)dt, \,\,\, 0\leq x <1. \end{equation}
for some $A,B>0$
Then, for example by Gronwall's inequality you have
\begin{equation*} f(x) \leq A e^{xB} \leq Ae^B < +\infty.\end{equation*}
For $0\leq x <1$. Similarly for $-1<x\leq 0 $.

Comment: Ah, Gronwall’s inequality - very nice.